# Curl - Капча - Авито

Tags: php, curl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Доброго времени суток! Ранее, при парсинге, у авито был немного другой алгоритм блокировки ip, при котором бан можно было обойти слипом на 6-8сек. 
Но, иногда случалось, что бан все равно ловил. 20-30 мин пройдет и все ок .. Терпимо!

Сейчас,видимо, авито немного поменял алгоритм и бан чаще выскакивает . Но не бан создал сложность для меня, а выход из него . 
Теперь нужно ввести капчу, чтобы выйти из бани. Капчу пытаться разгадывать сейчас не вижу смысла, т.к времени очень мало , а вот в ручную иногда ее писать - это нужно, т.к баня не часто возникает при парсинге.

Сложность : при открытии страницы блокировки через CURL капча не хочет отображаться  (ошибка 403). Значит посылаться должен какой-то дополнительный параметр, чтобы её отобразить ..
Куки стоят.. Где копать ? За ранее спасибо !

```
function curl($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'./cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'./cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "captcha=8дя1ц&yes");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,"https://www.avito.ru"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36');  
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $page;
}
$content=curl("https://www.avito.ru/blocked");

echo '<base href="https://www.avito.ru" />';
echo $content;
```

Comment: **403** - Тебе нельзя. Догадка что они проверяют хедеры, скорее всего (`Origin:http://...`  `Referer:http://`...) ... может что то еще. откройте нормально в браузере и посмотрите.

Comment: Запустите Fiddler, сравните запрос отправляемый curl и браузером, приведите первый ко второму.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. 
роюсь в хедерах .. Они отличаются .. 
Подскажите, почему не могу установить хост ?
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.avito.ru'));`
в фаербаге все ровно мой сайт висит

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343110/cant-set-host-in-curl-php `"Host: ". parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST),`

Comment: к сожалению, не получается .. Ставлю так 

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host:".parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))); `

и все ровно стоит мой сайт.. ((

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том что это немного не законно/этично. Поэтому можно попробовать. http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php и писать хедеры самому(не факт что получиться).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: https://github.com/php-http/socket-client

Comment: Программист сайта явно говорит вам, что не хочет допустить автоматического опроса данных, а вы спрашиваете нас, как нарушить правила сайта? Ваш вопрос не достоин ни малейшей симпатии.